# How to write dplyr statements as data table statements?

Tags: r

I have this code snippet.

```
mat <- retail %>% 
       select(Description) %>% 
       unique() %>% 
       mutate(value = as.numeric(Description %in% customer_order)) %>% 
       spread(Description, value) %>% 
       as.matrix()
```

Basically I'm dcasting and converting it into a matrix.
How do I write the same statements into **data table** format?

Comment: It would help if you include a simplified minimal dataset to make your question reproducible: Ideally include dataframe or similar object rather than the print version of your data. Like this: df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(retail)

as.matrix(
  transpose(
    unique(retail[, 'Description'])[, value := as.numeric(Description %in% customer_order)],
    make.names = "Description"))
```

Since you only have one variable to "cast", there is no need to do that.

---

**Data**:

```
retail <- data.frame(ID=1:8, Description=c("R","I","S","F","U","N","N","N"), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
retail

customer_order <- c("F","U","N")

library(tidtverse)

retail %>% 
  select(Description) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(Description %in% customer_order)) %>% 
  spread(Description, value) %>% 
  as.matrix()

#     F I N R S U
#[1,] 1 0 1 0 0 1

library(data.table)
setDT(retail)
as.matrix(
  transpose(
    unique(retail[, 'Description'])[, value := as.numeric(Description %in% customer_order)],
    make.names = "Description"))

#     R I S F U N
#[1,] 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Umm.. I need to dcast the Description with the new value column. I dont have one variable to dcast

Comment: The deprecated `spread` function from tidyr is simply transposing the data frame and converting the `Description` values to column names. This is exactly what the code above does but using data.table functions. You can see that the results are exactly the same using my toy data (except for the ordering of the values - `spread` sorts while  `transpose` doesn't).